# Does there exist a non-constant function $f:\mathbb N^2 \rightarrow \mathbb N$ such that $f(x,y)+f(y,x)=f(x^2,y^2)+1$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> Does there exist a non-constant function $f:\mathbb N^2 \rightarrow \mathbb N$ such that 
>   $$f(x,y)+f(y,x)=f(x^2,y^2)+1$$
>   for all positive integers $x,y$?

*I think that such a function does not exist. But I do not know how to prove*

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Aren't we free to choose $f(x,y)$ when $x$ or $y$ is not a square, and then to complete the definition of $f$ using $f(x^2,y^2)=f(x,y)+f(y,x)-1$ recursively? For example, $f(256,81)=2f(4,3)+2f(3,4)-3$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this function?

$$ f(x, y) = \begin{cases} 2^n + 1 & \text{if } (x, y) = (2^{2^n}, 1) \text{ or } (1, 2^{2^n}) \\ 1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Comment: perhaps $(2^{2n},1)$?

Comment: @TakahiroWaki, At each 'recursive step', the exponent is doubled: $ f(2^{2a}, 1) = 2f(2^a, 1) - 1$. So the exponent of the argument should be geometric itself.

Comment: Is this all possible function?

Comment: @TakahiroWaki As in **Did**'s comment, you are free to choose any value for $(x, y)$ with at least one of $x$ and $y$ being not square. Then you can construct a solution from the functional equation.